# How to show similar app available on play store?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I want to link my one app to another app in google play store just like in the picture. So when the user clicks on View it will directly move to the my another similar app.

[View in the picture of google play store app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFyE9.png)